# Is there an arbitrary precision float in F#? Something like BigFloat?

Tags: f#, floating-point

Is there a data type in F# that lets me calculate a float to an arbitrary/large number of decimal places? Something like the floating point equivalent of BigInt.

I would like do something like

```
 myLargeFloat = 1.0/7.0
 printfn "%12.500f" myLargeFloat // get the recurring cycle "0.142857142857142857...<500 digits long>"
```

I was using the BigInt to get the precision by multiplying the numerator with a bigint like so.

```
 myLargeFloat = (bigint.Pow(10I,500)/7I)
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigRational in the F# Powerpack is defined like this:

```
   [<CustomEquality; CustomComparison>]
   [<StructuredFormatDisplay("{StructuredDisplayString}N")>]
   type BigRational =
       | Z of BigInteger
       | Q of BigRationalLarge
```

Where a `BigRationalLarge` is defined as:

```
[<CustomEquality; CustomComparison>]
type BigRationalLarge = 
    | Q of BigInteger * BigInteger
```

To Print a `BigInt` with 1000 precision do something like this:

```
let factorial n = Seq.fold ( * ) 1I [1I .. n]

printf "Factorial of 1000 is %A" (factorial 1000I)
```

Taken from [here](http://diditwith.net/2007/10/26/ImReallyDiggingF.aspx).

Looking at the `BigRationalLarge` type [here](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/71313#1233622):

There are a number of ways to convert it to a different type to print:

```
   static member ToDouble(n:BigRational) = 
        match n with
        | Z z -> ToDoubleI z
        | Q q -> BigRationalLarge.ToDouble q

    static member ToBigInt(n:BigRational) = 
        match n with 
        | Z z -> z
        | Q q -> BigRationalLarge.integer q 

    static member ToInt32(n:BigRational) = 
        match n with 
        | Z z -> ToInt32I(z)
        | Q q -> ToInt32I(BigRationalLarge.integer q )
```

The conversion to a double looks like this:

```
   static member ToDouble (Q(p,q)) = 
        ToDoubleI p / ToDoubleI q
```

The default way of printing it as a numerator and denominator combination:

```
   override n.ToString() =
        let (Q(p,q)) = n 
        if q.IsOne then p.ToString() 
        else p.ToString() + "/" + q.ToString()
```

None of that really helps us get more precision.  There is no way to print it while specifying the number of decimal places to print.

So to answer your question:

You could make a function that prints the values you want, using the two `BigInt` parts of a `BigRational` or you could write an entirely new type to do this for you, but there isn't anything like that right now.

Answer (score 2):

There is a BigRational type in the [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/). See also http://tomasp.net/blog/powerpack-numeric.aspx

Comment: So, how do I print out the decimal points though? printf "%A" prints out 1/7 and printf"%12.500f" says that the BigRational type is not compatible with floats.

Comment: @Chaitanya From the referenced blog post, you simply cast to float like this : `float myBigRational`

Comment: But casting it to a float immediately causes it to lose precision though. When I did `let input1 = 1N / 7N
let input2 = float input1
printfn "%12.500f" input2` it printed out `0.142857142857143000000000000...`

Comment: It looks like you're on your own on this one. `BigRational` doesn't support what you want.  See my post for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you *truly* require arbitrary-precision floats, you'll have to use @mydogisbox's method. If you just need something with better precision than `float` (i.e., `System.Double`) you can try using the `decimal` type; it's an alias for `System.Decimal`, which is the .NET implementation of 128-bit binary-coded decimal (BCD). It's much more precise than `float` but much slower too (like 10-20x).